Hide bottom bar without resize lag
I want to hide the bottom navigation bar in when a specified action is triggered by code. Everything seems to work as expected except with the version I am currently having the UI lags a bit and after a second the screen is expanding and taking the space of the bottom navigation bar. I think the best approach would be to be able to dynamically set the height of the bottom navigation bar while hiding and between for instance 0 to 60 height. But it doesn't let me animate the height of the bottom bar with the reason:

Error: Style property 'height' is not supported by native animated
module

Do you have any ideas how I can smoothly hide and show the bottom navigation bar while being on the screen? I want to include a webview into the screen and if a subdomain is opened the bottom nav bar should hide. Here is my current code to handle this problem that is not working:
    const App = () => {
  const [tabBarHeight] = useState(new Animated.Value(60)); // Initial height of the tab bar

  const hideBottomBar = () => {
    console.log('hideBottomBar');
    Animated.timing(tabBarHeight, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  };

  const showBottomBar = () => {
    console.log('showBottomBar');
    Animated.timing(tabBarHeight, {
      toValue: 60, // Adjust this value to the height you need
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Tab.Navigator
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "green", height: tabBarHeight},
              }}
            >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Business" component={BusinessScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="School">
              {() => <SchoolScreen hide={hideBottomBar} show={showBottomBar} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
          </Tab.Navigator>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

I am running on React Native 0.74.2

You're going to need to post the versions of everything you're on, RN underwent a major overhaul this past 12 months so the solution will likely be different based on the versions of react/RN/RNreanimated your on

I alos realize that you might be using Animated from RN 0.74. If thats the case have you tried useNativeDriver: true? you could also try to animate with the scaleX scaleY properties instead of height

I am running on 0.74.2. I have tried ScaleY, it is animating which is good but the animation doesn't look good because it is reducing the bottom and the top side of the bar towards its center and I want to have an animation which is reducing the height of the bar and is collapsing towards the bottom of the screen. Any other properties that I could animate?

I have tried "useNativeDriver: true" but still the same error.

Instead of using height of Tab.navigator you can also use a custom
 const renderTabBar = (props: React.JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & BottomTabBarProps & { style?: false | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle> | Animated.Value | Animated.WithAnimatedObject<ViewStyle> | Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<string | number> | Animated.WithAnimatedArray<ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle> | RecursiveArray<ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle>> | readonly (ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle>)[]> | null | undefined; }) => (
<Animated.View style={[styles.tabBar, { transform: [{ translateY }] }]}>
  <BottomTabBar {...props} />
</Animated.View>);

This tab bar you can use in your tab.navigator with
tabBar={(props) => renderTabBar(props)}

And by using the transform property of the Animated.View you can easily animate the tab bar hiding or showing it with those two methods:
const hideBottomBar = () => {
Animated.timing(translateY, {
  toValue: 100, // adjust this value to the height of the tab bar
  duration: 300,
  useNativeDriver: true,
}).start();}; 

and
const showBottomBar = () => {
Animated.timing(translateY, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 300,
  useNativeDriver: true,
}).start();};

